# How can I set Microsoft Account permissions for shares without regards to domain on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, file-permissions, microsoft-account

I have folder A on computer A and I am mapping network drive on computer B to \VPN_IP\A, but I want full control permissions to the share from computer B.  Both computers use the same Microsoft Account to log in, but there is no concept of domains.  How can I set share permissions based on the Microsoft Account instead?

Answer (score 0):

Shares have properties.  (Right click)

Included in the properties you should see a Sharing Tab, and an Advanced Sharing button.  From there you can adjust the permissions.

Incidentally, my share permissions were Everyone Full Control.

In summary a) Believe it's possible.  b) If necessary use remote desktop to computer A.  c) Drill-down until you find the permissions settings.

Comment: How does that help me set permissions for a Microsoft Account (not a local account)?